# Crear Floating Action Buttons en un Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Mi objetivo es crear 3 botones desplegables. Me da un error de NullPointerException. Este código es copiado de un vídeo, el problema es que estaba programando en Kotlin, y mi caso es Java, así que puede que sea por un error de traducción, pero he sido incapaz de localizarlo. Dejo por aquí el código y el error:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

FloatingActionButton fab;
FloatingActionButton fab1;
FloatingActionButton fab2;
FloatingActionButton fab3;

Animation rotateOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.rotate_open_anim);
Animation rotateClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.rotate_close_anim);
Animation fromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.from_bottom_anim);
Animation topBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.to_bottom_anim);

Boolean clicked = false;

public ProfileFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,
            container, false);
    ImageButton edit_password_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
    ImageButton edit_email_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_email);

    // Edit password
    edit_password_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            if (v == edit_password_button) {

                // Creación de los fragmentos
                Fragment changePasswordFragment = new changePasswordFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, changePasswordFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();

            }
        }
    });

    // Edit email
    edit_email_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            if (v == edit_email_button) {

                // Creación de los fragmentos
                Fragment changeEmailFragment = new changeEmailFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, changeEmailFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();

            }
        }
    });

    // FAB
     fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_button);
     fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_empresa);
     fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_help);
     fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_settings);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onFabButtonClicked();

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void onFabButtonClicked() {

    setVisibility(clicked);
    setAnimation(clicked);
    clicked =! clicked;
}

private void setVisibility(Boolean clicked) {

    if (!clicked){

        fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        fab1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fab2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fab3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void setAnimation(Boolean clicked) {

    if (!clicked) {

        fab1.startAnimation(fromBottom);
        fab2.startAnimation(fromBottom);
        fab3.startAnimation(fromBottom);

        fab.startAnimation(rotateOpen);

    } else {

        fab1.startAnimation(topBottom);
        fab2.startAnimation(topBottom);
        fab3.startAnimation(topBottom);

        fab.startAnimation(rotateClose);

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La línea 26 es en la que creo la primera animación.

También he intentado cambiar el getContext() por getActivity() pero el error persigue.

También dejo el vídeo del cual me he fiajado por si fuera necesario:
[Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umCX1-Tq25k)

Comment: Para referirte al contexto desde un fragmento debes usar `getActivity()` y todo lo relativo a la vista conviene que lo pongas dentro de `onCreateView`. ¿Has probado a probar la creación de animaciones a ese método?

Comment: Tu problema no son los FAB, son los Animation que estas declarando fuera del onCreateView.